# Why this line of Shell works in eval() but get failed in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, eval, cut

Worked out a simple Shell script as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
SHOWIT="echo \"a b c\""
GETIT="cut -f 3 -d' '"
echo "$SHOWIT|$GETIT"
eval "$SHOWIT|$GETIT"
$SHOWIT|$GETIT
```

The expression "$SHOWIT|$GETIT" worked via eval, but hit error when put it to Shell command directly.

```
echo "a b c"|cut -f 3 -d' '
c
cut: ': No such file or directory  <== Hit error at here
```

BTW, my default shell is BASH 4.1.2 on RHEL6.3.

```
#bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Anyone could help find the root cause for the error? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Because with eval your command becomes like this:

```
echo "a b c" | cut -f 3 -d' '
```

But with word splitting only, your command is only like this:

```
echo "\"a" "b" "c\"" | cut "-f" "3" "-d'" "'"
```

Variables don't get double-parsed i.e. it only gets word-split once and quotes inside it is just ignored.